# NDEigensystem convergence and comparison to DEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, convergence

Consider the following eigenvalue differential equation

$$
-u_n''(x)+x^2u_n(x)=E_nu_n(x),\qquad x\in(-\infty,\infty).
$$

If you know a little bit of physics, you would know that this is the differential equation for a quantum harmonic oscillator, and that the energies are exactly given by

$$
E_n=2n+1,\qquad n=0,1,2\cdots
$$

We can also confirm this using Mathematica

```
 {eig, func} = DEigensystem[-u''[x] + x^2*u[x], u[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 5];
 ListPlot[eig]
```

[image: exact]

This is the expected result. But things go wrong quickly if we want to solve this numerically. In that case our code will look like

```
 {eig, func} = NDEigensystem[-u''[x] + x^2*u[x], u[x], {x, -1000, 1000}, 10];
 ListPlot[eig]
```

[image: numerical]

We expect the numerical calculation to converge to the exact calculation when we increase the bounds of $x$ but that does not happen. As we increase the boundaries, the energy eigenvalues blow up, and they do not converge.

I had the same experience using NDEigensystem for other complicated scenarios ([NDEigensystem eigenvalue convergence problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250980/ndeigensystem-eigenvalue-convergence-problem)), and therefore I wanted to frame the problem in this simple case. Is there something fundamental, or am I completely butchering NDEigensystem. Any help regarding this question and the linked question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You're setting so large a domain for approximation of $\infty$ that the default grid is too coarse to accurately describe the eigensystem. Try `{x, -5, 5}` instead:

```
{eig, func} = NDEigensystem[-u''[x] + x^2*u[x], u[x], {x, -5, 5}, 10];
eig
(* {1.00016, 3.00109, 5.00381, 7.0094, 9.01882, 11.0328, 13.0513, 15.0712, 
17.0803, 19.046} *)
```

Or setting a denser grid:

```
{eig, func} = 
  NDEigensystem[-u''[x] + x^2*u[x], u[x], {x, -1000, 1000}, 10, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}}];
eig
(* {1., 3., 5.00001, 7.00002, 9.00003, 11.0001, 13.0001, 15.0001, 17.0002, 
19.0003} *)
```