# Numerically compute the eigenvalues and eigenstates of a two-order partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

The objective is to numerically compute the eigenvalues and eigenstates of a stationary Schrödinger equation in an arbitrary polynomial potential. The equation takes the form:

$$
\left[-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V(x)\right] \psi(x) = E \psi(x)
$$

where, for example, $V(x) = x^2 + x^4$. Although there are approximate analytic methods available for this problem, they fail when the potential $V(x)$ becomes complex. Therefore, we need a general numerical method to accomplish this task. I try to do this in Mathematica. My code is

```mathematica
(*Step 1:Define the potential function*)
v[x_] := x^2 + x^4;
(*Step 2:Set up the Schrödinger equation*)
eqn = -1/2*D[D[u[x], x], x] + v[x]*u[x] == energy*u[x];
(*Step 3:Specify the boundary conditions*)
boundaryConditions = {u[-10] == 0, u[10] == 0};
(*Step 4:Solve the eigenvalue problem*)
{eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eqn, boundaryConditions}, u[x], {x, 10, 10}, 10];
(*Step 5:Extract the eigenvalues and eigenvectors*)
eigenvalues
eigenvectors
```

However, my code doesn't work. The desire results include a set of eigenvalue like $E_n = E_1, E_2, \cdots$ and correspondingly, the eigenstate are $\psi_n = \psi_1, \psi_2, \cdots$ which satisify $H\psi_i = E_i \psi_i$

Comment: You should look into the correct syntax for [`NDEigensystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html), because you are using it wrong. Please study this code which works fine: `(*Step 1:Define the potential function*)
v[x_] := x^2 + x^4;
(*Step 2:Set up the Schrödinger equation*)
eqn = -1/2*D[D[u[x], x], x] + v[x]*u[x];
(*Step 3:Specify the boundary conditions*)
boundaryConditions = {u[-10] == 0, u[10] == 0};
(*Step 4:Solve the eigenvalue problem*)
{eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = NDEigensystem[{eqn}~Join~boundaryConditions, u[x], {x, -10, 10}, 10];`

Comment: Namely: (1) Instead of the full equation $H\psi=E\psi$, you have to provide just the left side $H\psi$. (2) Equation and boundary conditions should be given in a single list.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to say: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Domen! The code works! I do have one more question, however.

I wnat to verify the accuracy of the code. Let's use a well-known case in quantum mechanics: the Harmonic potential, represented by $V(x) = x^2$. For this potential, the eigenvalues are expected to be equidistant, specifically $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{2}, \ldots$. However, I find our numerical results have much error.

Is there any suggestion on the boundary condition? Should I let `u[-Infinity]=0` and `u[Infinity]=0`?

Comment: You will find an answer and an explanation in [_NDEigensystem convergence and comparison to DEigensystem_](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250998/ndeigensystem-convergence-and-comparison-to-deigensystem).

Comment: Thank you very much, all the answers is fulfilled.

Answer (score 6):

You have taken the $x$ limit from $10$ to $10$. It should have been $-10$ to $10$

Try the following code.

```
L = 10;
V[x_] := x^2 + x^4

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-1/2*Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + V[x]*u[x], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, -L, L}, 10];
```

---

## Eigenfunctions

[image]

---

## Eigenvalues

[image]

---

### Harmonic Oscillator

```
L = 10;
V[x_] := x^2/2

{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{-1/2*Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + V[x]*u[x], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, -L, L}, 10,Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" ->{MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}}}}]
```

---

**Eigenfunctions and  Eigenvalues**

[image]

Comment: The code you've posted for the harmonic oscillator [does not give](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjGLe.png) such accurate eigenvalues that your plot is showing.

Comment: I appreciate the response from @user444. Furthermore, this question has been answered perfectly in [NDEigensystem convergence and comparison to DEigensystem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250998/ndeigensystem-convergence-and-comparison-to-deigensystem). With the methods provided there, accurate results can be obtained even for high level.

Comment: @Domen, Please see the edited response for finding the accurate eigenvalues. I've added a `Method` to the existing code.